# Why does this RSA padding error occur when changing the language?

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption, rsa

so I'm trying to encrypt data in C# with RSA and decrypt it with JavaScript also with RSA.

This is the function that I use to encrypt the data in C#:

```
private static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] input, bool server)
{
    byte[] encrypted;
    using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(4096))
    {
        rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
        if (server)
        {
            rsa.ImportParameters(ImportPublicKey(Main.PUBLIC_KEY_SERVER).ExportParameters(false));
        }
        else
        {
            rsa.ImportParameters(publicKey);
        }
        encrypted = rsa.Encrypt(input, true);
    }
    return encrypted;
}
```

And this is the code I use to decrypt the data in JavaScript:

```
function decryptMessage(encryptedMessage, privateKey) {
    console.log(encryptedMessage);
    const rsaPrivateKey = {
        key: privateKey,
        passphrase: '',
        padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
    };

    const decryptedMessage = crypto.privateDecrypt(
        rsaPrivateKey,
        Buffer.from(encryptedMessage, 'base64'),
    );

    return decryptedMessage.toString('utf8');
}
```

Now the problem is I'm always getting the Error:
`Error: error:04099079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error`

And I don't know why. For some reason, the Encryption Padding doesn't seem to be the same anymore. Is there a way around this problem?

~Louis

Comment: RSA has different options.  One is the padding option.  The default Java and Net library settings for padding are different.  So you need to change the padding in one to match the other.

Comment: Provided that encoding and decoding works correctly, there are still options. OAEP is not a single algorithm but can be parametrized by hash functions. I think by default SHA1 is used but this default can be different depending on the runtime/language.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer but to be honest, I don't know how to parameterize it in any of these two languages, cause in C# You can only use true or false to tell the System if it should use OAEP or not and in a don't know which algorithm it is using so I would love to find an Answer to that.